# In coffescript click function does not work for ipad?

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, responsive

Hello I am using coffeescript. I need a click event. I have following code:

```
node.on("mouseover", showNodeDetails)
.on("mouseout", hideNodeDetails)
.on("click",fillInfo)
```

This works for my personal computer. However when I try to use it on ipad, nothing happens when I click the node (neither hover nor click events are triggered).

What is the problem and how can I solve it.Thanks for any help